# dynamic routeLink can not display URL

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-cli

[image]

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor= "let p of  products$ | async ">
            <td>{{p.title}}</td>
            <td>{{p.price}}</td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink] = "['/admin/products/', p.key]" >Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


{
    path: 'admin/products',
    component: AdminProductsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin/products/new',
    component: ProductFormComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    **path: 'admin/products/:id',**
    component: ProductFormComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
  },
```

hello, friends!

u can see  the blue word "Edit" below in the picture.
i expect it to show amdin/product + 'URl' , but it turns out admin/product/undefined.

and aslo I give code above I writed for this function purpose,  where is my problem ????

besides, i got no complian error both in cmd and chrome console.

Regards!

Comment: <a [routerLink] = "['/admin/products/', p.key]" >Edit</a> ```key``` is not present in object.

Comment: try using `<a [routerLink] = "[p.key]" >Edit</a>` or `<a [routerLink] = {{p.key}} >Edit</a>` rather `<a [routerLink] = "['/admin/products/', p.key]" >Edit</a>` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your edit link you are using `p.key` as shown below,

```
 <a [routerLink] = "['/admin/products/', p.key]" >Edit</a>
```

but in products array you are not getting `key` field in `product` object of that array. so `p.key` will be undefined

Comment: how could that be possible it can be anything `p.key` doesn't matter i guess.

Comment: if it is not provided then `p.key` will give `undefined` and route will become like `/admin/products/undefined`.

Comment: @jaibalaji, If he/she used keyvalue pipe, then p.key will have value else it will return undefined.
Ref: ```https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fqhhsw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts```

Comment: @zhiqiangshu if your using firebase then you can get the ID while fetching data. Let me know if your issue is not resolved. or add new question for the same.